# Unable to attach click event to a dynamically created button

Tags: javascript

I have created a javascript function to dynamically create a button

```
function btn(d) {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode(d);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.className = "myButton";
    btn.onclick = alert('hello');
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

when this function is called, alert is poping up even if button is not clicked. I want the alert when button is clicked. May be i am missing something. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the whole context in which this function is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling the alert function not assigning a function

```
alert('hello'); // evals immediately.

btn.onclick = function () {
    alert("Hello World"); // gives the button a click handler 
                          // which can be called when clicked
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it with jQuery, like so (per your jQuery tag on the question):

```
function btn(d) {
    var btn = $('<button/>').addClass('myButton').text(d).appendTo('body').click(function (e) {
        alert('hello');
    })
}
```

Comment: OP is not using jquery.

Comment: @TomDDD OP tagged the question jQuery, so it is assumed they are looking for a jQuery solution.

Comment: Thanks 
Actually was using this function inside another jquery function so tagged jquery also @TomDDD

Answer (score 0):

onclick should look like:

```
btn.onclick = function(){alert('hi');};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the return value of `alert('hello');` to the `onclick`, while it is expecting a function. The correct way without jQuery would be

```
if (btn.addEventListener)
  btn.addEventListener ('click',function(){ alert('hello');}, false);
else if (btn.attachEvent)
  btn.attachEvent ('onclick',function(){ alert('hello');});
```